# How to remove malware package from android phone

Tags: malware

My android phone has been affected with malware.I have done factory reset two times  but it still installs **UC News** app without  authorization when connected to  internet.After that many pop-ups and confirm boxes randomly pop-up on window.  After factory reset,I don't have any third party app installed. Where can I get a list of apk packages that are supposed to come with new android phone,so that I can remove it using adb?

Any other suggestions what should I do?

Comment: The list of pre-installed apps very much depends on vendor, device and Android version – there is no "generic list". You could list the apps which are installed after a factory reset, or the system apps in general, via ADB: `adb shell "pm list packages -s"`. If some malware made it into your system, the cleanest way out is to factory-reset and then flash a clean ROM.

Comment: my android version is kitkat. Since factory reset is not working, I will flash ROM.

Comment: Don't forget to wipe, the malware might hang around somewhere waiting to reintroduce itself.