# how to flash ROM in xolo opus3 with sd card?

Tags: rom-flashing

My android phone has been affected by malware.From the suggestions of my last [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/166468/how-to-remove-malware-package-from-android-phone) I'm trying to flash ROM to my phone by following  this [link](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-flash-a-rom-to-your-android-phone-30885281). In recovery mode the options I get are

```
reboot
apply update from adb
apply update from sd card
apply update from cache
wipe data/factory reset
```

and few other options
After selecting apply update from sd card , it doesn't recognises the zip stored in sd card.
Another method I read is using Sp flash tool,but it is not availble for linux 32 bit.
How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

The zip file is not recognised probably because it's not a recovery flashable zip file. You need **[SP Flashtool](http://spflashtool.com/)** to flash the device.

- Download this [firmware](http://www.mediafire.com/download/0aqnj5rh4bci752/XOLO_Opus3_S008_13092014.zip)  and save it to the desktop then extract it.
- Download MTK CDC and preloader drivers from [here](https://androidmtk.com/download-mtk-usb-all-drivers)
- Open SP Flash tool (download from above link) and click on **Scatter-Loading**
- Browse to where the firmware is extracted and select the scatter file (a .txt file)
- SP Flashtool should load all the file. Preferably untick all the check mark except for the **android slot** as you need  only the system partition to be flashed.
- **UNTICK the preloader** slot (IMPORTANT), this will prevent the device from completely dead if something goes wrong.
- Click on Download (Green arrow), power off the device, connect it to the computer and wait to till the end. You'll have a Green checkmark if the process succeed.

Comment: not able to find linux 32bit flash tool. Downloaded one from [link] (http://spflashtool.com/download) ,but getting error **cannot execute binary file: Exec format error**

Comment: You're on a Linux computer?

Comment: yes, ubuntu xenial

Comment: I didn't find neither. You should try on Windows

Comment: Hey @esQmo, I tried with adb sideload command using the ROM from the link you have provided. I'm getting installation aborted.

Comment: @ashwinids Simply because it's now a recovery flashable ROM.